# Regular expression wtih an escaped closing bracket at the end

Tags: java, regex

This is a java/regular expression question.

I like to search for this `"M(x)"` in a text string in a java program using the following snippet:

```
public static List<String> findPattern(String patternStr, String value)
{
    ArrayList<String> matchedStrings = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);          
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matchedStrings.add(matcher.group(0));
    }
    return matchedStrings;
}
```

The following pattern string works:

```
M\\\\(x\\\\)
```

The following pattern doesn't:

```
\\\\bM\\\\(x\\\\)\\\\b
```

I like to use `\\b` such that I can find a match with text `"M(x) = abc"` and NOT `"TM(x) = abc"`.  It is really interesting, with all the testing that I had done, the `"\\b"` seems to fail ONLY if the character right before that is an escaped bracket.

Is there something that I do wrong?  Or is there something that can achieve the same objective?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: `\b` is a word boundary, and matches between a word and a non-word letter (or start/end of string). You might want to use `\\bM\\(x\\)\\B` (`\B` is an opposite class).

Comment: What makes you think that in-between `) =` there is a word boundary?

Comment: I had a generic function to find any "word/phrase" within a text string and locate all its occurrences and then do something with it...  So, until now, I was lucky with the search "word/phrase".  I was also confused because if I do something like this: "M(x) is something".replaceAll("\bM\\(x\\)\b", "XYZ"), that function seems to find the pattern and replace the text.

Answer (score 1):

See, \b is a *word boundary anchor*. In other words, it marks a place right in between word characters (letters, digits, underscore) and non-word ones (the rest).

The point is, both ')' and ' ' (space character) are non-word characters, so there is no word boundary between them. If you expect it in your pattern, it'll just fail.

So, you can just drop the trailing \b from your pattern, turning it into...

```
 \\bM\\(x\\)
```

Answer (score 0):

The ending `\b` wont work in your case because `\b` matches :

> After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
>   (http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

Why do you need the second `\b` ?
Can you provide different testcases and expected results ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `.*?(M\(x\))`. `.*?` means non-greedy match.

```
String txt="sdda2asddaTM(x) = abcsdssdcxc";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?(M\\(x\\))", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(txt);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.print(m.group(1));
    }
```

You will not get `TM(x)`